Use pandas operations to transpose and reindex
I have the following dataframe:
           Sample ID  'Deinococcus soli' Cha et al. 2014  16SrX (Apple proliferation group)  16SrXII (Stolbur group) 
0   C1day1_barcode01                                  21                                  1                        0
1  C1day21_barcode19                                  22                                  0                        0
2   C3day1_barcode03                                  13                                  0                        0
3  C3day14_barcode15                                  14                                  2                        2
4  T1day21_barcode22                                  19                                  1                        1

This is my desired output:

                              Sample ID  C1day1_barcode01  C1day21_barcode19  C3day1_barcode03  C3day14_barcode15  T1day21_barcode22
0    'Deinococcus soli' Cha et al. 2014                21                 22                13                 14                 19
1     16SrX (Apple proliferation group)                 1                  0                 0                  2                  1
2               16SrXII (Stolbur group)                 0                  0                 0                  2                  1


I have used transpose and I tried inserting a new index & renaming the columns as well as resetting the index but in either cases I get something like this:
0                           Sample ID                 0                 1                 2                 3                 4
0                           Sample ID  C1day1_barcode01  C1day21_barcode19  C3day1_barcode03  C3day14_barcode15  T1day21_barcode22
1  'Deinococcus soli' Cha et al. 2014                21                 22                13                 14                 19
2   16SrX (Apple proliferation group)                 1                  0                 0                  2                  1
3             16SrXII (Stolbur group)                 0                  0                 0                  2                  1

or
Sample ID                            index  C1day1_barcode01  C1day21_barcode19  C3day1_barcode03  C3day14_barcode15  T1day21_barcode22
0  'Deinococcus soli' Cha et al. 2014                21                 22                13                 14                 19
1   16SrX (Apple proliferation group)                 1                  0                 0                  2                  1
2             16SrXII (Stolbur group)                 0                  0                 0                  2                  1

Though I tried renaming index to Sample ID I'm unable to remove the "Sample ID" title of the index even by setting index.name = None. What do I do?

What if you do df.set_index('Sample ID').T on the original dataframe?

set_index on the "Sample ID" column to set it aside, transpose to reshape, rename_axis to exchange the axis names, and reset_index to move back the IDs as column:
out = (df.set_index('Sample ID').T
         .rename_axis(index='Sample ID', columns=None)
         .reset_index()
      )

Alternative:
col = 'Sample ID'

out = (df.set_index(col).T
         .rename_axis(index=col, columns=None)
         .reset_index()
      )

Output:
                            Sample ID  C1day1_barcode01  C1day21_barcode19  C3day1_barcode03  C3day14_barcode15  T1day21_barcode22
0  'Deinococcus soli' Cha et al. 2014                21                 22                13                 14                 19
1   16SrX (Apple proliferation group)                 1                  0                 0                  2                  1
2             16SrXII (Stolbur group)                 0                  0                 0                  2                  1

